# Should I resolve all my dependencies at the root level?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm building an application for which I'm using Dependency Injection and since I do use a lot of dependencies I'm having trouble understanding where I need to resolve those dependencies:

Let's say that I'm writing a fairly complex console application and the application together uses 100 interfaces that are all registered in an IoC container.

Does that mean I need to resolve all those 100 interfaces in the constructor of my root method (because otherwise I'm not using Dependency Injection anymore).

Any tought on this or how this is resolved in modern days?

Kr,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear to me what you mean by "resolve".  If you mean, do you need to instantiate all of your objects in the composition root, then no.  They get instantiated when you create the upper level dependency.

If you mean, do you need to register all the dependencies in the composition root, then yes.  However, depending on the framework you're using it may be possible to use a convention over configuration method to do so without explicitly specifying each dependency.

If by "root method" you mean the constructor of any given class, then yes, you need to instantiate all objects that the class depends on (and any objects those objects depend on) when you create the class.

When using dependency injection, creating objects should be cheap.  If you have expensive objects, then you should defer instantiation of the expensive part until you actually use it, through some kind of Lazy method or Factory.

Comment: Thanks, this make sense. But doesn't it make the code real cluttered by instantiating 100+ objects in the root?

Comment: @Complexity - That depends.  Again, read my second paragraph.  However, even if you do create each reference manually then this is only one place it's cluttered, and you can always refactor this into sub-methods for organization.

Comment: Do you know any containers that are useing "Convention Over Configuration" and what's is called then so I can search a bit upon them.

Comment: @Complexity - StructureMap uses them pretty frequently, SimpleInjector has extensions to do it, as do most others.  Which one are you using?  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753241/simple-injector-register-all-services-from-namespace